# Column width using tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

for my GUI I want to use a grid with 6 columns. The size of the table is set. How do I fill the width of the grid with the columns? Can you set the size of the columns? I only found `padx` to change the padding, but not the actual size of the columns.
For now, this is supposed to work on a canvas. Is that even possible?

Comment: Maybe try to use `ipadx`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA That doesn't seem to work either. padx/ipadx just add additional space next to the contents of the elements. Can't I set the width of the elements, regardless of content?

Comment: What's the element?`Label`?`Button`?or?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Labels. I forgot to just change the size of the labels *facepalm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only the information you passed i would recommend you following:

Grid layouts your objects. Its not a table.

If you work with grid here. The simplest thing should be to set the width of the object you put on the wanted grid. For example:

> If you add a Label set the label to the width you want it to be. This label will then
>   be displayed in the grid with its width and height.

If you want to display a table. Or even better load a table from a database. I would recommend a Treeview. Its good for design allows multiselect and its easy to fill and you dont have the layout problems :)

Comment: Wow, changing the size of the labels is such an easy solution *facepalm. I seriously didn't think of that.
I'm trying out Treeview now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah i searched for tables in tkinter too for a long time. Had to display a database and Treeview was the best solution. :)

Comment: It works so well all of a sudden. Was working on that for a couple of hours before and got it done in half an hour now. This might come in handy for a couple other projects too now.

Comment: The treeview? :D

Comment: Yes, I don't know how I never heard of it before ^^
Can you change the background and foreground color easily?

Comment: yes you can. also for each column itselfe. I for example had one white one gray one white one gray :D looks kinda nice :D

Comment: How do you do that? We tried a couple of times and couldn't figure it out

Comment: Try to google Treeview customizing or something like that. I worked with tags. So I had 2 states. Open and fixed. So while inserting into the treeview i checked it and set the tag to fixed or open. The tag itself then had the customization like background color etc.

Comment: Or you work with a boolean which you set True and False after every line you inserted. If its True make the line dark gray if its false make it light gray. Something like this :D

Answer (score 2):

If you've fixed the size of the table, you can configure the columns to each be 1/6th the width of the window as a whole. The trick is to give each column the same non-zero `weight`, and use the `uniform` option. The `uniform` option takes a string, and all columns with the same value will be the same width.

If you run this code, notice  how you can resize the window and the columns will automatically resize as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

columns = []
for i in range(6):
    frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief="raised", background="bisque")
    columns.append(frame)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
for column, f in enumerate(columns):
    f.grid(row=0, column=column, sticky="nsew")
    root.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1, uniform="column")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of small window]
[image: screenshot of large window]

Comment: Oh thanks, that is an interesting approach. I switched to using treeview now. Do you have experience with that? Do you know how to change the color of the background of the heading?